# How to get all attribute in class?

Tags: python

```
class Test():
    test1 = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.test2 = 2

r = Test()
print r.__dict__
print getattr(r,'test1')
```

Why I don't see test1 attribute in `__dict__` dictionary ?

Comment: Because `test1` is in the classes dict. Try `type(r).__dict__`. To get all the attributes though try `dir(r)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`instance.__dict__` contains instance attributes, not class attributes.

To get class attributes, use `Test.__dict__` or `type(r).__dict__`.

```
>>> r = Test()
>>> print r.__dict__
{'test2': 2}
>>> print Test.__dict__
{'test1': 1, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x000000000282B908>}
>>> print getattr(r,'test1')
1
```

Alternatively you can use [`vars`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> print vars(r)
{'test2': 2}
>>> print vars(Test)
{'test1': 1, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x000000000282B908>}
>>>
```